# No "Get in touch" ability?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users, messaging

I have found constantly that I am trying to talk to users yet I am constantly dragged down by the fact that we are spamming the living daylights out of comments. Why do we not have an ability to post on someone's profile or message them? While you would have to limit this to a certain reputation personally it would seem very helpful.

Comment: Random this is not a duplicate. He has a far different idea than I do.

Comment: Sending direct messages between users. I don't see it as a "far different" idea.

Comment: He wants to email I want more of like a post on their page. Also he talks about money I don't. Those are two very different ideas.

Comment: Think of facebook vs Gmail

Comment: drop a comment asking them to come over to [chat]

Comment: It's effectively the same thing - asking for some sort of personal message feature.

Comment: Facebook =/= Gmail.

Comment: So? Direct messaging of any form has been declined by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Where was it declined?

Comment: Why not drop a comment and then talk in chat like Sathya sugested? I've exchanged my cell number with users in chat, but that doesn't mean I want random people bugging me. I would _never, ever, ever_ want to see a PM feature on SE. We're so far from Facebook and Gmail, and I would like it to _stay that way._

Comment: It doesn't have to be like either. There just needs to be a way for users to get in contact with other users without having to post on a answer. I could care less how it is done.